# Omniture data reporting on a 301 redirecting page

Tags: javascript, html, analytics, adobe-analytics

We have used Omniture reporting for submission of basic metrices like page views etc through JavaScript on the webpages.

A recent requirement requires us to do a 301 redirect on a page.  Now, this necessarily means that the JavaScript will not execute on the page visit by the browser.

How such metrices can be tracked in Omniture.  With Google Analytics, I know we have a set of APIs that let you do custom reporting.

I would like to know if someone has done it in certain way or people are aware of the best practices for doing such a requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you login to the SiteCatalyst interface, KB article 543 will explain all the details you are looking for.